# Load external HTML file in a panel in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to load an external html file in a panel in Sencha Touch 2.3.1.

While doing my research I found this Stack Overflow post: [How to load external html file in panel or container sencha touch 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488085/how-to-load-external-html-file-in-panel-or-container-sencha-touch-2-3).

When I tried to use the code from there, it failed.

I found no errors in the console.

I tried to post it in Sencha forum, but the system is logging me out for unknown reasons.

I do not have enough reputation to comment in that post or ask this in chat.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/y5Gur7yi

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.Panel',
            config: {
                id: 'MyPanel',
                itemId: 'MyPanel',
                scrollable: true,
                listeners: [
                    {
                        fn: 'onMyPanelActivate',
                        event: 'activate'
                    }
                ]
            },
            onMyPanelActivate: function(newActiveItem, container, oldActiveItem, eOpts) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: '../test.html',
                    success : function(response) {
                        Ext.getCmp('MyPanel').setHtml(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure : function(response) {  
                        var text = response.responseText;
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', text, Ext.emptyFn);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I always use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#MyPanel')[0]

Comment: @PeterKellner Can you provide a simple and complete example please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I wrote to do what you are doing.  Hope this helps.

```
if (!detailPanel.tpl) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            scope: this,
            //local path of your html file
            url: '/Data/Templates/CodeStarsSummitPresenterDetail.html',
            success : function(response) {
               detailPanel.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(response.responseText);
               detailPanel.update(datas);
            },
            failure : function(response) {
                var text = response.responseText;
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', text, Ext.emptyFn);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        detailPanel.update(datas);
    }
```